# How to tell heroku to use rails 3 and ruby 1.9.2 for a newly created app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I created a new app on my machine using rvm ruby1.9.2p0 and rails 3.0.1, and did the following:

```
rails new -J -d mysql appname
git init
git add .
git commit
heroku create
```

and the app is created. but when i do:

```
heroku rake db:create --trace
```

I get:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
Couldn't create database for {"reconnect"=>false, "encoding"=>"utf8", "username"=>"root", "adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"app_production", "pool"=>5, "password"=>nil, "socket"=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci
(in /app)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
```

and when i do:
    heroku rake db:migrate --trace, then the trace has lines like:

```
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in
```

which shows it is using ruby 1.8 instead of ruby 1.9.2

How can I create a database on my heroku app and make it use ruby 1.9.2p0?

Answer (score 7):

If you've already created the application on Heroku it will have defaulted to 1.8.7 as you've found. You can specify the stack to create the application on when you create your app;

```
heroku create myapp --stack bamboo-mri-1.9.2
```

To migrate your app to 1.9.2 you will need to issue

```
heroku stack:migrate bamboo-mri-1.9.2
```

Once migrated you will need to repush your application (if i remember correctly)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the Ruby or Rails version.

The problem here is that you are trying to use MySQL while [Heroku only supports PostgreSQL](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database).

In [this page](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack) you can find the instructions to migrate to a different Heroku stack.

Comment: what's interesting here then is that Heroku didn't rewrite the database.yml file to use their share Postgres instance.

Comment: Just to be totally correct, Heroku supports MySQL no problem at all - you can use the Amazon RDS addon or connect to your own MySQL instance outside of Heroku

Comment: Interesting, @John answers the question the author asked but @Simone gave the "real" answer. So which one do I upvote??

Comment: go with you heart :) and remember Heroku DOES support MySQL! :)

Comment: @John ok, I decided to upvote yours since @Simone didn't answer the actual question. If someone googles their way here then your answer will be more useful.